# Test cases are not working on remote web driver but working fine on local

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I created the smoke test cases using selenium c#. My code is working fine on local browser but when I switched to remote web driver test cases are failed only the landing page test case is passing.

I think there might be some setting I am missing.

Can anyone one help me on this if faced same issue.
[image: Please look into the attached screenshot. Does it affecting to locate remote server?]

Comment: Can you please add more details like the error message and scope of the driver.

Comment: Unable to find element error I am getting, but same url is working fine on local.